# Why does the code with the concurrent.futures.thread skip widget operations?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

***The goal is to first perform actions on widgets (create Button_1 and remove Button_2) and then enable speech recognition.***

I should definitely use the concurrent.futures.thread module.

In this attempt, the compiler goes through each line-this is evidenced by the output of lines marked with `#for test` comments. ***Problem: speech recognition works, but actions with buttons (create Button_1 and remove Button_2) occur only after exit from functions voiceRecognition:***

```
def someFunc(self, event):
    print('Interface change started') #for test
    #creates Button_1
    #deletes config.Button_2 (from another func)
    print('Interface change finished') #for test

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        fut = executor.submit(self.voiceRecognition)

def voiceRecognition (self):
    print('Voice recognition was started') #for test
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as sourse:
        audio = r.listen(sourse)
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(query.lower())
        print('Voice recognition was finished') #for test
```

Output :

```
Interface change started
Interface change finished
Voice recognition started
Voice recognition finished
```

Here is, as and that with buttons specifically (separately from context they work, and work normally) :

```
config.Button_1 = wx.Button(self)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.eventFunc, Button_1)
config.Button_2.Destroy()
```

Help me to understand the causes of problems and their practical solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is

> 1.you are only calling one thread for the voice recognition function which only runs one time
>
> 2. my second guess would be that these functions are not i/o bound functions

The way threads work is another function starts while the previous is waiting for a particular data to be received or something similar. If there are no such requirements then threads are not very useful[image]

The point which the second function starts running is the point at which the first function is waiting to receive some resource. If this is not your requirements you may want to look into multiprocessing or async/await functions(using the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) package)

```
import asyncio

async def someFunc(event):
    print('Interface change started') #for test
    #creates Button_1
    
    await event() #when code runs with voiceRecognition past as the event parameter, that is what will run here

    #deletes config.Button_2 (from another func)
    print('Interface change finished') #for test

def voiceRecognition ():
    print('Voice recognition was started') #for test
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as sourse:
        audio = r.listen(sourse)
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(query.lower())
        print('Voice recognition was finished') #for test

 asyncio.run(someFunc(voiceRecognition)) #to run it asynchronously
```

I do not really know how your class looks so i have written it as a typical function, meaning you will have to adapt it a little to fit your code.

> Notice the change to how your `voiceRecognition()` is called in `someFunc` using your *event* parameter and also notice the position event is now called at in `someFunc`

Comment: @maestro-inc, Thank you, you helped me understand a lot... This is really not my case and using threads does not suit me. The fact that I tried to use asyncio, but it turns out somehow rotten. The code in this case looks like this:

Comment: @maestro-inc, `def someFunc(self):
        #creates config.Btn_1
        #deletes config.Btn_2                         
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.<..>(self.voiceRecognition())

    async def voiceRecognition (self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        chekV = 1
        while chekV == 1:
            with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as sourse:
                audio = r.listen(sourse)
                query = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(query())
                if query == 'Stop':
                    chekV = 0`

Comment: @maestro-inc, ... But 1-button actions still happen after the "voice Recognition" function is finished, 2-all the things I tried to put in place <...> output errors and I'm desperate. Can you help me solve this, please?

Comment: i have updated my answer. Although if your plan is for the output to be `interface change started  voice recognition started voice recognition finished interface change finished` then you actually do not need threads or async(because the response would be synchronous) what may be more helpful would be multiprocessing, but this problem looks i/o bound so i am guessing there will likely not be a difference in your programs execution time